# Sort authors via last name in Tiddlywiki

Tags: tiddlywiki, tiddlywiki5

It would be good to sort lists using an author's last name.

I have this code in one of the tiddlers, it lists all the tiddlers tagged 'author' and sorts alphabetically:

```
<$list filter='[tag[author]sort[title]]'>

</$list>
```

e.g.

```
Adam Robinson
Andrew Adonis
Benjamin Franklin
Dale Carnegie
Daniel Priestley
George Leonard
```

I would like the list to be sorted by last name, so it looks like this:

```
Adonis, Andrew 
Carnegie, Dale
Franklin, Benjamin
Leonard, George
Priestley, Daniel
Robinson, Adam
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: What does this have to do with Markdown or HTML?

Answer (score 0):

**Easy option:** Add a ByLastName field populated the way you want and sort on that.

**Medium option:** Introduce the notion of generated fields into tiddlywiki.

**Hard option:** Modify the sort filter to call a macro with whatever data you specify and then sort the original list based on the result.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of TiddlyWiki, you can do this with the `sortsub` [operator](https://tiddlywiki.com/#sortsub%20Operator), which sorts based on the results of applying a filter expression to the inputs. Note that when you use this operator (or any other operator that takes a subfilter), you have to define the subfilter using a [macro](https://tiddlywiki.com/#Macros), or there's no way for TiddlyWiki to tell which square brackets are part of the main filter and which are part of the subfilter.

Here's a minimal working version:

```html
\define myfilt() [split[ ]last[]]

<$list filter="[tag[author]sortsub<myfilt>]">
  ...
</$list>
```

To get the display to show up as "Lastname, Firstname", as in your example, rather than just showing the title of the tiddler as is:

```html
\define myfilt() [split[ ]last[]]

<$list filter="[tag[author]sortsub<myfilt>]">
  <$set name=formattedName value={{{ [all[current]split[ ]last[]addsuffix[, ]] [all[current]split[ ]butlast[]] +[join[]] }}}>
    <$link to=<<currentTiddler>>><<formattedName>></$link><br>
  </$set>
</$list>
```

We calculate the new format using a filter in `{{{ triple curly braces }}}` and assign it to a variable (note the use of `butlast[]` rather than `first[]` so that if someone has more than two names, the middle ones go on the end rather than disappearing). Then we create a link whose text is that new formatted version, and whose target is the original tiddler name.